# Hide column based on parameter - SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, business-intelligence, reportbuilder

I have a table with two columns, I want to hide column **position** when the parameter is single select (multiple value is available).

Have parameter **@position** which contains 5 values (PG, SG, SF, PF, C)
Table look like this

```
playersName   Position
    
Julio         C 
Julio         PF
Kristofer     PF    
Kristofer     SF
Belle         PG    
Marcella      SG
Adam          PG
Adam          SG
```

So if I select just **SG**, I want to hide entire column players and just left
playersName column with values (Marcella and Adam) as in eg.

Tried few things inside visibility expression, but I was unsuccessful.
Do you have some other ideas?

EDIT:
I need expression for SSRS, because I want to hide column in report builder

Comment: Why are you using an unsupported version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hide the Position column set the hidden property of the column to this

```
=Parameters!position.Count=1
```

When a single item is selected the column will be hidden.

Your dataset query can be set to something like

```
SELECT playersName, Position
    FROM myTable
    WHERE Position IN (@position)
```

Comment: =Parameters!position.Count=1 is working just fine - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.playersName = t.playersName and
                    t2.position = @position
             );
```

Comment: I do not need sql query, I need expression for SSRS and how to hide column in ssrs report

Comment: @Neca24 . . . Then it is probably best not to tag the question "sql".